# Unable to change branches, remotely deleted file invisible in local repo

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I've created a branch from master, made a PR. Somewhere along the line two files src/A/A.tsx and src/a/A.tsx made its way into the remote repo before I turned on git's case sensitivity. I removed the src/A/A.tsx file on github repo, because I wanted to only keep src/a/A.tsx. I've made a PR with this branch. Now when I try to make and switch to new branches, this error appears.

"Unable to checkout when changes are present on your branch. The following files would be overwritten
src/A/A.tsx
You can stash your changes now and recover them afterwards. "

Pressing "Stash Changes and Continue" in github desktop doesn't do anything.
I'm not seeing src/A/A.tsx in Finder, nor when `git status`. How do delete src/A/A.tsx and get back the ability to switch branches?

Comment: I'm able to switch branches with `git checkout master -f`. But if I go back to that other branch in question, the error comes back.

Comment: I suppose you're on Windows (or other OS with case insensitive names). You probably can remove it from the index directly? `git rm --cached src/A/A.tsx` maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm on macOS but others may have Windows. `git rm --cached src/A/A.tsx` does not find a file, only `git rm --cached src/a/A.tsx` does, but that deletes the files I actually want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `git config core.ignorecase true` I can once again switch branches. Hopefully everything will be fine once I push again.

Comment: Try disabling that again and do `git ls-files` and verify that the files are listed according to git. It will show the upper and lower case files, despite what you have in your working directory. You shouldn't have to do this, there's a way to check the files.